# How to make react-router work on serverless app?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

It seems react-router won't work if it don't have an express server to handle routes e.g.

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')));
```

Is there a way to remove this dependency?

Comment: react-router works without a server, it handles the routing on the client side. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It stop working when you refresh the page and not on index route.

Comment: I'd like to deploy it on github pages.

Answer (score 0):

React-router doesn't have anything related with server unless you use server-side rendering. It works in browser, using history API.

Please make sure you use BrowserRouter or HashRouter instead of StaticRouter and follow documentation precisely.

Comment: react-route won't work if I refresh the page while on different route

Comment: @sandaemc What happens after you refresh the page? Blank page?

Comment: I got 404 not found when I pushed it to github pages.